# how to get youtube subtitle through youtube id

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to extract the transcripts from youtube video.

I can get it for video such as: 
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=G7djoQfncRw

But when I try it for another video such as:
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang_code=en&v=QWq7vUMdowQ

I get:

XML Parsing Error: no element found

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Checking contentDetails for that video show that no manually entered captions are available.

```
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT12M7S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   },
```